# what is the best way to change BaseUrl in constants component depending on Login condition in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, constants

I have a login screen in react native project. It only accepts phone numbers of US or Indian country code only. Right now I am dispatching the information to redux from login screen like below:

```
Login.js
--------------
let BaseUrl;
    if (userLoginModel.code === '+91') {
      dispatch(setNonUS());     
      
    } else if (userLoginModel.code === '+1') {
      dispatch(setUS());     
      
    }
```

And I want to setup my constant.js file like below, it worked when I had single BaseUrl declaration. But when I do as shown in below code. I get error saying Invalid hook call.

```
//constants.js

import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


let BaseUrl;
const isUS = useSelector(state => state.settings.isUS);
if (isUS) {
  BaseUrl = 'https://us.herokuapp.com/api/v1';
} else {
  BaseUrl = 'https:/india.herokuapp.com/api/v1';
}

export {BaseUrl};


const customersHub = BaseUrl + '/customers';
const salesHub = BaseUrl + '/sales';

 export const EndPoint = {

   login: customersHub + '/addCustomer',
   getSales: salesHub + '/getSalesOfCustomer',
   getCustomer: customersHub + '/getCustomer',

}
```

How do I fix the above constant.js file so that my other components can still import the baseUrl like so:

```
Other components
-------------------
import {BaseUrl} from '../../utility/constants'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking the Rules of Hooks, which state a hook can only be called at the root level of a React function component. If you want to use the selector value within your function, you could pass it in from inside a component.

```js
export const getBaseUrl = (isUs) => isUs ? 'https://us.herokuapp....' : 'https://india.herokuapp....'

// in component
  const isUS = useSelector(state => state.settings.isUS);
  const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(isUs);
```

There are many ways of doing this - this is just one. The important thing is to only call hooks inside function components.